# Data import from excel to R (all columns are character classed)

Tags: r, excel, csv

I'm new to r and really need some help with an assignment i have for school.

So I've created an xls file containing returns for companies as decimals i.e 0.023 (2.3% return)

Data is in 3 columns with some negative values. titles for each column in the first row. No row names present just 130 observations of returns and the company names (column names) at the top. All the cells are formatted to general

I converted the xls file to csv on my mac so the file type became CSV-UTF-8 (comma delimited).

When i try to create a dataset in r I imported the csv using `read.table` command:

```
read.table(”filename.csv”, header = TRUE, sep =”;” row.names=null)
```

The dataset looks good all the individual numbers in the right place but when I try

```
Sapply(dataset, class)
```

All columns are character. I've tried `as.numeric` and it says list object cannot be coerced to type ’double’

Comment: You should provide an exemple of your dataset by adding the output `dput(dataset)` in your post

Comment: structure(list(companyx.returns= c("0,016753",...."0,014253,"","","",""),companyY.returns=c("0,016753",...."0,014253,"","","",""),companyZ.returns=c("0,016753",...."0,014253,"","","","")), row.names= c(NA,-130L), class = "data.frame")
Thats the output of dput(data frame) I took out some numbers so the ... between the first and last number of the specific companies represents the numbers left out. Hope this helps and thanks for fast feedback!

Comment: This is not convenient for us if you removed some parts as we can't reproduce your dataset. If your dataset is too large, I recommend that you give us `dput(head(dataset))`, this would be more useful, thanks

Comment: using dput(head(dataset) I get: 
structure(list(Apple.returns = c("0,016872342", "0,003428012", 
"-0,021361084", "-0,018348007", "-0,001610414", "0,006143667"
), Tesla.returns = c("0,016987205", "0,012613501", "-0,038604853", 
"0,003302554", "0,001534737", "0,015231904"), Starbucks.returns = c("0,007574407", 
"0,003577178", "-0,014019928", "-0,010988053", "0,000261689", 
"-0,035503954")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: My solution in answer

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from the fact that you imported a dataset with commas and R cannot interpret this as numeric (it requires dot as decimals separator).

Two ways to avoid this :

1. You import as you did and you convert your dataframe

```
dataset=apply(apply(dataset, 2, gsub, patt=",", replace="."), 2, as.numeric)
```

2. You directly import the dataset by intepreting commas as decimals separator with `read.csv2`

```
library(readr)
read.csv2("filename.csv",fill=TRUE,header=TRUE)
```